# sh script to remove just txt files using find and exec rm warns me of missing argument to exec

Tags: ubuntu, unix, bash, shell, find

```
find /full/path/dir -name '*.txt' -exec /bin/rm {} \;
```

Fine in a shell, but pop it in a sh script along with some similar lines, to get it to run nightly from a cronjob, and it reports:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

on everything. I've tried backslashes and quote-marks in possibly every combination.  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have Windows line endings in your script file. Try running `dos2unix` on it to convert them.

You can reproduce this error at a shell prompt with:

```
$ find ... \;^M
```

Where you add "^M" by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>m</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! I simply used "fromdos <file>" and everything is working perfectly. I don't know why the fact I'd also tried xargs got edited out of my original post, you've solved it with a simple solution. Many thanks again.

Comment: @talkingnews: I don't know why @larsks was a bit overzealous with the editing. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine why

```
find /full/path/dir -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

wouldn't work.  To test your cronjob, do something like this:

```
find /full/path/to/dir -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 >/tmp/logfile
```

which will just echo what xargs would delete into `/tmp/logfile` so you can check manually.

Comment: Damn Phil, you're too fast ;)

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when find doesn't match any files with that criteria, then tries to execute rm with an empty stack and it returns that error.

Phil suggestion is amazing though, so please mark him up! :)

Comment: ha you came up with the correct reason for why it fails sometimes so +1!  In general I avoide -exec.

Comment: `find` *won't* try to execute the `-exec` if there are no results.

Comment: same here, I so much prefer your method through xargs, it's way more elegant

Comment: I had that issue several times Dennis, when you use -name and it returns empty it tries to return `-exec`, which is annoying as hell :/

Comment: `find -name '' -exec echo something {} \;` doesn't print anything. Can you give a specific example of what you're describing?

Comment: I can reproduce that on a linux environment by having * in the -name ... but here's the funny thing, I can only reproduce on RHEL, on some Ubuntu servers I have it's working fine (grr annoying) I reckon it can be due to env values?

Comment: Are you quoting the argument to `-name`? If you do `-name foo*`, for example, you can get unexpected behavior since the glob is expanded by the shell. To delay that so it's expanded by `find` do `find -name 'foo*'`. Also, reply to comments using @Dennis so I'm automatically notified of the reply.